# Parse .json file locally using $.getJSON

Tags: jquery, json

So I have a .json file in a data directory. I am using

```
$.getJSON('data/source.json', function (data) {         
    console.log(data.name); //or
    console.log("say something");
});
```

I see the file come in on the network tab in chrome dev tools but I never get a console message nor does a break point stop anywhere after that. Eventually, I will have a web service spitting this out but for designing the app I need some local JSON. Can anyone help?

Comment: do you get response with just console.log(data); ..?

Comment: Is the javascript running locally?  (i.e. begins with file:// in the URL?)  Chrome doesn't allow local XHR, try firefox to see if you get different results.

Comment: Hi Sudhir no I do not get anything back. I can throw this on a web server and I get console message all the same.

Comment: does the `preview` of the response found in the network tab looks correct?

Comment: @stevanity yes it does. I upload the json to a server and then locally point to it. I get nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same problem. I do not know what causes the problem, but simple name change from source.json to source.txt helped me.

edit: browsers do not allow local request to .json files. For Chrome and Firefox you can install the JSONView add-on to fix the problem. But, as I mentioned, simple name change works.